# C nested struct initialization - what is initialized?

Tags: c, struct, initialization, declaration, zero-initialization

Let's say I have struct S:

```c
typedef struct
{
  int x;
  int y;
} S;
```

Then:

```c
S s; // s is uninitialized here.
```

And:

```c
S s = {}; // s is initialized (zeroed) here.
```

Now let's say I have struct T:

```c
typedef struct
{
  S s1;
  S s2;
} T;
```

And I initialize it like this:

```c
  T t = {}; // is t completely initialized?
```

I'm just guessing that `t.s1.x` can contain a random value, right?

Do I have to write:

```c
T t = {{}, {}};
```

Is it necessary to have `t.s1` and `t.s2` initialized / zeroed?

Then, if I write:

```c
int a[8];
```

Is it 8 zeroes, or 8 random values, that most likely are zeroes?

Again, I'm guessing I should write

```c
int a[8] = {};
```

... to have 8 certain zeroes, but I'm not sure.

What about:

```c
T[8] = {};
```

Is it 8 initialized `T`s, or 8 uninitialized / random `T`s?

How do you properly initialize / zero such nested structs and arrays?

By initialization I mean just having zeroes everywhere.

Comment: No, everything will (should AFAIK) be initialized to zeros.

Comment: I guess you'd prefer explicit initialization in case if different compilers behave differently. Use a function to create a new struct and make sure that every struct initialized properly inside that function.

Comment: In C youd normally work with allocated pointers to these structs, so some T_create function would have to be implemented so all initialization details are covered there explicitly. If its all zero then its just a calloc wrapper.

Comment: Note that using `{}` as initializer is invalid in C before the upcoming C23 standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the object `s` is initialized in this declaration

```
S s; // s is uninitialized here.
```

depends on where the declaration is placed. If the declaration is placed in a file scope then the object is zero-initialized as an object with static storage duration. If the declaration is placed in a block scope then the object is uninitialized as an object with automatic storage duration and has indeterminate values.

These all declarations

```
S s = {}; // s is initialized (zeroed) here
T t = {}; // is t completely initialized?
T t = {{}, {}};
int a[8] = {};
```

are invalid in C because you may not use empty braces to initialize objects.

To zero initialize for example the object `t` in a block scope you should write for example

```
T t = { 0 };
```

or

```
T t = { { 0 } };
```

To zero-initialize the array `a` (all its elements) in a block scope you should write for example

```
int a[9] = { 0 };
```

Comment: Will `T a[9] = { 0 };` be valid too?

Comment: @Harry Yes, it will be valid.